# Можно ли увидеть изменения в другой сессии до COMMIT в ней?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Я реализовал PL/SQL скрипт. В продуктивной среде скрипт запустит DBA.

Есть ли способ, увидеть изменения, которые произвёл скрипт, до того, как будет выполнен COMMIT?

Знаю, что изменения будут активны в той сессии, в которой выполнялся скрипт. Но может есть способ в другой сессии, или более того, с другим пользователем, увидеть эти изменения?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [See changes of a different SQL Oracle session before COMMIT?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65500207) от участника [@Felipe Vidal Otero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7994509/felipe-vidal-otero)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/65500207

Answer (score 4):

Пакет [DBMS_XA](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_XA.html) может передавать незафиксированную транзакцию из одной сессии в другой. Другая сессия может просматривать незафиксированные данные, может фиксировать, откатывать или снова передать их в другую транзакцию. Приведенный ниже пример основан на [этой статье ORACLE-BASE](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/dbms_xa_11gR1) и выглядит, что работает, но никогда не проверял в продуктивной среде, поэтому - на свой страх и риск.

### Сессия 1

Тестовая таблица и изменение тайм-аута на ветвление транзакций (по умочанию 60 сек.):

```
create table t1 (id number);

var ret number
exec :ret := dbms_xa.xa_settimeout(600);
```

Начните транзакцию с магическим числом транзакции (9999) и вставте первую запись:

```
exec :ret := sys.dbms_xa.xa_start (xid=>dbms_xa_xid (9999), flag=>dbms_xa.tmnoflags);

insert into t1 (id) values (1);
```

Завершим транзакцию, чтобы к ней можно было подключить другую сессию. Запись, которая была только что вставлена, будет больше не доступна в это сессии:

```
exec :ret := sys.dbms_xa.xa_end (xid=>dbms_xa_xid (9999), flag=>dbms_xa.tmsuspend);

select * from t1;

no rows selected
```

### Сессия 2

Изначально, эта сессия не может видеть данные:

```
select * from t1;

no rows selected
```

Подключиться к глобальной транзакции, используя то же самое магическое число (9999). Затем, только эта сессия может видеть новую запись. В залючение, эта сессия должна зафиксировать, откатить, или опять - отсоединится от транзакции:

```
var ret number
exec :ret := dbms_xa.xa_start (xid=>dbms_xa_xid (9999), flag=>dbms_xa.tmresume);

select * from t1
/

        ID
----------
         1

begin 
    :ret := dbms_xa.xa_end (xid=>dbms_xa_xid (9999), flag=>dbms_xa.tmsuccess);
    if :ret = dbms_xa.xa_ok then 
        :ret := dbms_xa.xa_commit (xid=>dbms_xa_xid (9999), onePhase=>true);
    end if;
end;
/
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65516565) от участника [@Jon Heller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/409172/jon-heller)</sub>